# Implementing Next and Previous Link in Gatsby Single Post

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

{mdx.frontmatter__slug}.js

```
export const query = graphql`
    query ($id: String) {
        mdx(id: {eq: $id}) {
            frontmatter {
                title
                date(formatString: "MMMM D, YYYY")
                slug
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

How is it possible for me to add `prev` and `next` link where there is nothing in GraphQL to index the current post? I'm thinking of going to the route of adding an `id` to frontmatter manually.

Any advise is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This involves using Gatsby's createPage API in your gatsby-node.js file. This API allows you to create new pages programmatically and pass context data to the page. This context data can be used in your GraphQL queries to fetch data for the specific blog post.
Let me know if it helps.